# Password Autofill iOS 12 not working properly

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I followed this guide: 
https://medium.com/developerinsider/ios12-password-autofill-automatic-strong-password-and-security-code-autofill-6e7db8da1810

I created a github page and put the json file in this structure: 
 snguyenevolution1.github.io/.well-known/apple-app-site-association.

I have the file validated here: https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/

Here is the entitlement: [image]

There is a saved entry for snguyenevolution1.github.io in keychain. But when I tap on the username/password text field, the quick type row above the keyboard only show Password, not password for snguyenevolution1.github.io.

After tapping on that password and verify my touch ID, it brings up the entire list of all saved password in keychain, and I can literally pick anything from that list. I want it to automatically select the entry like it does in the tutorial.

Could someone please point out what I'm doing wrong? I'm pretty positive that the ids are matched.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should set in entitlement Associated Domains like this `applinks:your_domain`

**References**

[Support Universal Links in your iOS App](https://developerinsider.co/enable-universal-links-in-ios-app-and-setup-server-for-it/)

[iOS12 - Password AutoFill, Automatic Strong Password, and Security Code AutoFill](https://developerinsider.co/ios12-password-autofill-automatic-strong-password-and-security-code-autofill/)

Answer (score 0):

Does it do this for all password managers?  I use 1Password 7 and it works ok.  Look in your accounts and passwords setting and make sure you have a password saved for that specific website.